# Check of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$ properties

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation

For function defined as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}
$$
check if  $f$ is continuous and differentiable function.

**My approach:**

I would like to use the connection between this sum  and some integral so tried to write that 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/n}{\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2+1}
$$
but don't know what to do now because of $1/n$ in numerator.

Answer (score 2):

By the Weirstrass-M test, and the bound
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
$f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as the uniform limit of continuous functions.

For differentiability, we really do the same thing, using the fact that if a sequence of functions $f_N$ is differentiable for all $N$, and $f_N$ and $f_N'$ converge uniformly, then the uniform limit is differentiable.

In our setting, this requires investigating the convergence of 
$$
f_N'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}=
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2}
$$
Which again follows from the Weirstrass M test. Indeed, use calculus to establish
$$
\frac{2|x|}{(x^2+n^2)^2}\leq 2\frac{n/\sqrt{3}}{(n^2/3+n^2)^2}=O(1/n^3)
$$
And conclude.

edit: as noted by @zhw, since differentiability is local, we may just show uniform convergence on compacts, establishing the bound on the differentiated partial sums for $|x|\leq a$,
$$
\left|\frac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2}\right|\leq\frac{2a}{n^4}
$$

Comment: For differentiability, you need only check $[-a,a]$ for each $a>0.$ That makes the estimate easier.

Comment: @zhw. that's a good point, I'll add a note

Comment: The estimate I see on the summand is $2a/n^4.$

Comment: @zhw. you are right, I forgot to square things in the denominator

Comment: @qbert why your inequality for derivatives is true - how to prove it?

Comment: @avan1235 maximize the function like you would in calculus. I.e. find an $x$ so that the second derivative of the terms is $0$. It is clear here that the derivative will have a maximum on the negative real axis and a minimum on the positive real axis but in absolute value they will be the same by symmetry.

Comment: @zhw. Why it is enough to check the function on $[-a,a]$ for each $a>0$?

Comment: If a function is differentiable on $[-a,a]$ for each $a>0,$ then it is differetiable everywhere (because any real $x$ will be in the interior of some $[-a,a].$)  @avan1235